# Pressing Enter for a new line on Visual Studio for Mac automatically tabs the new line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

So I have recently bought a new MacBook Pro and downloaded Visual Studio for Mac (The Beta version) since I didn't like the Code one. Whilst using it I have encountered a problem when I press the enter key, this being that when I press enter to create a new line under the current line, it automatically tabs the new line: [Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERfD1.png)

(If the embedded link doesn't work try this one: https://ibb.co/bAUmva the one above is given by Stack Overflow and didn't work on my laptop)

Furthermore, when I try to delete the white space produced it takes me back to the line above. It doesn't cause a problem with the actual code but I feel you can understand that it causes a fair bit on confusion and frustration when it's not all in line

I have looked on the shortcut references on Visual Studio but to no avail, moreover, I have not seen anyone with a similar problem on here...

Any help would be appreciated

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out why it happens, the auto tab occurs when there is an error in the code. Fixing the error automatically 'untabs' the code.